# How to find selector for "new" button? Do I need to use Switch frames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

```
<div id="crmMasthead" tabindex="-1">
<div id="crmTopBar" class="ms-crm-TopBarContainer ms-crm-TopBarContainerGlobal newNavBarMode">
<div id="crmAppMessageBar" class="crmAppMessageBar" style="display: none; height: 0px;">
<div id="crmRibbonManager" currentribbonelement="commandContainer15" style="height: 62px; display: block; visibility: visible;">
<div id="commandContainer15" style="display: inline;">
<ul class="ms-crm-CommandBar-Menu" role="application">
<li id="ewrb_importfile|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.HomepageGrid.ewrb_importfile.NewRecord" class="ms-crm-CommandBarItem ms-crm-CommandBar-Menu ms-crm-CommandBar-Button" tabindex="-1" title="New Create a new Import File record." command="ewrb_importfile|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.NewRecordFromGrid" style="white-space: pre-line; display: inline-block;">
<span class="ms-crm-CommandBar-Button ms-crm-Menu-Label-Hovered" tabindex="-1" style="max-width:200px">
<a class="ms-crm-Menu-Label" tabindex="0" onclick="return false">
<img class="ms-crm-ImageStrip-New_16 ms-crm-commandbar-image16by16" tabindex="-1" src="/_imgs/imagestrips/transparent_spacer.gif" style="vertical-align:top"/>
<span class="ms-crm-CommandBar-Menu" tabindex="-1" style="max-width:150px" command="ewrb_importfile|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.NewRecordFromGrid"> New </span>
<div class="ms-crm-div-NotVisible"> Create a new Import File record. </div>
</a>
</span>
</li>
```

The Xpath Shows me like this:

```
.//*[@id='ewrb_importfile|NoRelationship|HomePageGrid|Mscrm.HomepageGrid.ewrb_importfile.NewRecord']/span/a
```

and If i use this, Selenium doesn't click the button

Answer (score 0):

First try to remove "."(dot) from your xpath and check it if it works.

Secondly, try to write the xpath yourself. For this a node, try this one:

```
//a[@class="ms-crm-Menu-Label"]
```

You should check it if the part of html that you share is inside an iframe node or not. Otherwise, you should share more. With the current part that you shared, it is not possible to say that if it is inside an iframe or not.

Also, it can be a good idea to check the visibility of the button. The last thing: do you receive any error message. If yes, share it.